# MSB3027 I am consistently getting this error message

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, frameworks, bin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\CABDINAJIIB MAHAMED\Desktop\regSystem\regSystem\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\regSystem.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "regSystem (10692), regSystem (20724)"   regSystem   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  5150

i try to end task in my task manager but after some time it coming againbin

Comment: Clean project. Close VS. Make sure all instances have been killed in task manager. Try again. If unsuccessful, reboot and retry.

Comment: If it worked and it happens again, try to remember what you did to create the situation.

Comment: The file apphost.exe is being used and cannot be copied.

Comment: ^^ which means that something is still running. If you are unable to find the culprit, a reboot can help, but it's anything but graceful.